# Overlap between the maximum spanning tree and largest edges of a bipartite graph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Given $K_{m,n}$ a bipartite graph, what is the expected fraction of overlap that the set of the top/largest *m+n-1* edges would have with the maximum spanning tree (MST) of the graph?
Naively it has to be greater than $\frac{1}{m+n-1}$ since the largest edge of the graph must be a part of both sets.

Likewise, are there any known $(\varepsilon,\delta)$ bounds on the overlap? I.e., any identities stating how large the set of top-$k$ edges would need to be to ensure that its fraction of overlap with the MST is greater than some $\varepsilon$ with a probability of $1-\delta$.

The cases I would be most interested in are if the edge weights are sampled from any continuous distribution.

Comment: If you want to talk about expected overlap, or probability, you should specify a probability distribution first.

Comment: @MishaLavrov sorry about that, the two cases I would be most interested in are if the weights are sampled from $U(0,1)$ and the normal distribution

Comment: You've supplied the relevant piece of information: we take a complete bipartite graph and randomly assign edge weights. Any continuous distribution of costs will produce the same result.

Comment: I agree that any continuous distribution of costs would result in the same expected fraction of overlap; Though trying to have a non-asymptotic, $(\varepsilon,\delta)$ sort of bound would require explicit knowledge of the density function

Comment: No; the distribution is only necessary when we want to know the actual weight of the maximum spanning tree. But finding the maximum spanning tree only needs the rankings between the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm), one of the algorithms for a maximum spanning tree. This considers the edges in order from largest to smallest weight, and for every edge, it adds it to the spanning tree provided this would not create a cycle.

Thinking about the maximum spanning tree of the randomly weighted graph in this way, the following questions are equivalent:

- How many of the $k$ highest-weight edges of $G$ end up in the maximum spanning tree?
- If we choose $k$ random edges of $G$, how many edges are in the largest acyclic graph we can form from them?

---

Rather than consider a complete bipartite graph, I will look at just a complete graph first, because this case is more well-studied: it is the [Erdős–Rényi model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) of random graphs, where we take $n$ vertices and choose $m$ random edges between them. What is known is that:

- Suppose we choose $m = cn$ edges for $c < \frac12$. Then with high probability they only form a constant number of cycles.
- When $c>\frac12$, the graph undergoes a phase transition. The $m$ edges create a *giant component* with a constant fraction of the vertices, and many cycles. The remaining components are small, and mostly have no cycles, though a few have one. By a Poisson approximation, there are around $e^{-2c}n$ isolated vertices.
- The graph becomes connected around $\frac12 n \ln n$ edges, when the last isolated vertex disappears.

In the maximum spanning tree world, this says:

- The top $\frac12 n$ edges are almost all in the maximum spanning tree.
- Of the top $n$ edges, some constant fraction is in the spanning tree (more than $\frac12$, by monotonicity, but less than $1 - e^{-2}$, because of the isolated vertices, which are part of the problem but not all of it). The exact constant is annoying.
- The top $\frac12 n \ln n$ edges contain almost all the edges of the maximum spanning tree.

---

If instead of a complete graph, we are weighting the edges of a complete bipartite graph, the general picture stays the same but the constants vary. I'll do a couple of examples; you can interpolate.

First suppose our host graph is $K_{n,2n}$. Let's switch to the model where we pick each edge independently with probability $p = \frac cn$. Then the expected number of cycles of length $2k$ is roughly $\frac1k n^k (2n)^k p^{2k} = \frac{(2c^2)^k}{k}$, and the sum $\sum_{k \ge 2}\frac{(2c^2)^k}{k}$ converges for $c < \frac{\sqrt2}{2}$. So the phase transition happens at $p = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2n}$, when we pick $\sqrt 2 n$ random edges.

Meanwhile, the probability that a vertex is isolated is $e^{-2np}$ for a vertex on the smaller side and $e^{-np}$ for a vertex on the larger side. When $p = \frac{c \log n}{n}$, this gives $n^{1-2c}$ isolated vertices on the smaller side and $2n^{1-c}$ isolated vertices on the larger side, so $c=1$ is the point at which almost all the isolated vertices on the larger side have disappeared. At this point, we have $2n \log n$ edges.

In summary:

- Of the top $\sqrt 2 n$ edges, almost all get used;
- Of the top $3n$ edges, some constant fraction get used;
- Almost all edges of the spanning tree are in the top $2n \log n$ edges.

It's also informative to consider the host graph $K_{10,n}$ where $10$ is fixed and $n$ is large. Here, we can be more precise. The vertices on the small side take a constant number of edges to connect, so we can ignore them. We just want to know: how many vertices on the large side are isolated?

By a Poisson approximation, the average number of such vertices after we pick $k$ edges is $n e^{-k/n}$. Therefore after $cn$ edges, there are $e^{-c}n$ isolated vertices, so approximately $(1 - e^{-c})n$ of the top $cn$ edges are part of the spanning tree.